# protobuf-net and serializing a linked list using interfaces

Tags: serialization, interface, protobuf-net

I have come across a problem with protobuf-net and have narrowed it down to this simplest case.
I want a linked list type structure, where a class has a property of the same type.  When I serialize this it works great.  However if the type is an interface instead of a class I get the following error: 
The type cannot be changed once a serializer has been generated for ConsoleApplication1.foo (ConsoleApplication1.ifoo)

This is the code I have to generate this error:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var toSerialize = new foo();
        toSerialize.data = "foo1";

        var subf = new foo();
        subf.data = "foo2";

        toSerialize.subfoo = subf;

        using (var pbfsc = new FileStream("testfile.proto", FileMode.Create))
        {
            using (var cs = new GZipStream(pbfsc, CompressionMode.Compress))
            {
                ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(cs, toSerialize);
            }
            pbfsc.Close();
        }
    }
}

[ProtoContract, ProtoInclude(2000, typeof(foo))]
public interface ifoo
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    string data { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    ifoo subfoo { get; set; }
}
[ProtoContract]
public class foo : ifoo
{

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string data { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public ifoo subfoo { get; set; }
}
```

I have done all the reading on the subject I can and I can't see what I have done wrong.  I tried putting my object in a wrapper class as it looks similiar to a problem with lists of interfaces (code not shown) and this still didn't help.

If I change subfoo to type foo then it works fine, but in my more complex real world problem I would rather stick to using interface.  Have I done something wrong here or is this a problem with protobuf-net?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Alex

Answer (score 1):

There is some outstanding work that needs completing to improve the treatment of the *top level* object when it implements an interface that is a contract. Basically, at the moment it only processes the non-interface parts of the root object, but handles interfaces for properties / sub-objects etc.

The exception you are seeing is *slightly* odd - I would expect it to have known about `ifoo` in time, due to the `subfoo` property, but the fundamental problem here can be avoided by adding:

```
Serializer.PrepareSerializer<ifoo>();
```

before the serialization code (ideally somewhere pretty early; you only need to call it once).

However, I should also note that you're actually double-serializing here: when serializing the `ifoo subfoo` property, it will serialize the decorated members from *both* the interface (`ifoo`) *and* the concrete type (`foo`). These are actually the same values, so there is some redundancy here.

I *would* say: take the member-level attributes off the concrete type, but the root-object glitch makes this slightly problematic. Another fix, that solves *both* issues (no longer requiring the `PrepareSerializer`) is:

```
using ProtoBuf;
using System;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var root = new foo();
        root.data = "foo1";

        var subf = new foo();
        subf.data = "foo2";

        root.subfoo = subf;
        var toSerialize = new FooRoot { root = root };

        // this does the same as your file-code, but runs
        // both serialize and deserialize - basicaly, it is
        // a lazy way of checking it end-to-end
        var clone = Serializer.DeepClone(toSerialize).root;
        Console.WriteLine(clone.data); // "foo1"
        Console.WriteLine(clone.subfoo.data); // "foo2"
    }
}
[ProtoContract]
public class FooRoot
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public ifoo root { get; set; }
}
[ProtoContract, ProtoInclude(2000, typeof(foo))]
public interface ifoo
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    string data { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    ifoo subfoo { get; set; }
}
[ProtoContract]
public class foo : ifoo
{
    public string data { get; set; }
    public ifoo subfoo { get; set; }
}
```

When the root-object/interface-support glitch is resolved, the `FooRoot` wrapper would not be needed, but I'll probably need to add some switch to enable/disable the fix, for legacy support.