# ProtoBuf-Net, deserialization of two lists where one is part of another

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

Banana List contains references to objects in Fruits List. Bananas in Fruits List are placed one after another. Furthermore they have ascending numbers. (Adding and deleting bananas should preserve these properties) Problem is that after deserialization Bananas List and Fruits List in Basket seems to contain different objects. Is there way to avoid it ?

My second question is about property ContainedBy in Banana. Cos Bananas are aware where they are they point at specific container but again after deserialization they are pointing god know where (to be specific to other basket than they are contained in). Where is the catch?

```
    [ProtoContract]
    [ProtoInclude(500, typeof(Basket))]
    public interface IContainer
    {
        [ProtoMember(1, OverwriteList = true)]
        public List<Banana> Bananas { get; set; }

        [ProtoMember(2, OverwriteList = true)]
        public List<IFruit> Fruits { get; set; }

    }

    [ProtoContract]
    public class Basket : IContainer
    {
        [ProtoMember(1, OverwriteList = true)]
        public List<Banana> Bananas { get; set; }

        [ProtoMember(2, OverwriteList = true)]
        public List<IFruit> Fruits { get; set; }

        public void AddBanana()
        {
            var number = Bananas.Count;
            var newBanana = new Banana(number) {ContainedBy = this};
            var lastBanana = Bananas[Bananas.Count - 1];
            var index = Fruits.LastIndexOf(lastBanana);

            Friuts.Insert(index + 1, newBanana);
            Bananas.Add(newBanana);
        }

        public void DeleteBanana(Banana banana)
        {
            Bananas.Remove(banana);
            Fruits.Remove(banana);
            var n = 0;
            foreach (var b in Bananas)
            {
                b.Number = n++;
            }
        }
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    [ProtoInclude(600, typeof(Banana))]
    public interface IFruit
    {
        [ProtoMember(1, AsReference = true)]
        IContainer ContainedBy { get; set; }
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    public class Banana : IFruit
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public int Number { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(2, AsReference = true)]
        IContainer ContainedBy { get; set; }
    }
```

**Update #1** Answer given by Marc Gravell work very well for above problem. But my target feature is Dictionary of Containers and that gives an Exception: "A reference-tracked object changed reference during deserialization". Changes listed below are applied to Marc Gravell's answer.

```
[ProtoContract]
class RootObject
{
    [ProtoMember(1, OverwriteList = true, AsReference = true)]
    public Dictionary<string, IContainer> Dictionary { get; set; }
}

...

internal static class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var basketA = new Basket();
        basketA.AddBanana();
        var basketB = new Basket();
        basketB.AddBanana();
        var root = new RootObject {Dictionary = new Dictionary<string, IContainer>()};
        root.Dictionary.Add("A",basketA);
        root.Dictionary.Add("B",basketB);

        RootObject clone;
        using (var file = File.Create("tmp.bin"))
        {
            Serializer.Serialize<RootObject>(file, root);
        }

        using (var file = File.OpenRead("tmp.bin"))
        {
            clone = Serializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(file);
        }

        foreach (var container in clone.Dictionary.Values) //Exception
        {          
        Console.WriteLine(container.Bananas.Count == container.Fruits.Count); //true
        Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(
           container.Bananas[0],
           container.Fruits[0])); // true
        Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(
            container.Fruits[0].ContainedBy,
            container)); // false

        }           
    }
}
```

Obviously changing Dictionary tag in RootObject from `[ProtoMember(1, OverwriteList = true, AsReference = true)]` to `[ProtoMember(1, OverwriteList = true)]` helps with exception but reference ContainedBy is lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, protobuf-net is a tree-serializer, not a graph-serializer; so until you tell it to respect the references involved, it will serialize *separately* the information under bananas and fruits. Additionally, you need to be careful about the double-serialization, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12634742/23354). This same post also describes a current "needs work" area between interfaces and their classes, which may be impacting you here; I think I've largely worked around this by swapping the order of `Fruits` and `Bananas`.

Note that I've removed the "lastBanana / index" code for the simple reason that it was exploding when the lists were empty, and I didn't want to pre-empt your intentions there - I'll leave you to re-add that code.

My main thought, though, is simply: it looks like you're serializing your main domain model. There's nothing inherently *wrong* with that, but: if it ever starts to get tricky, then I always advise: switch to a simpler DTO model for serialization, and map to/from the DTO/domain models.

Anyway, the following seems to work:

```
using ProtoBuf;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[ProtoContract]
class RootObject
{
    [ProtoMember(1, AsReference = true)]
    public IContainer Container { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(500, typeof(Basket))]
public interface IContainer
{
    [ProtoMember(2, OverwriteList = true, AsReference = true)]
    List<Banana> Bananas { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(1, OverwriteList = true, AsReference = true)]
    List<IFruit> Fruits { get; set; }

}

[ProtoContract]
public class Basket : IContainer
{
    public List<Banana> Bananas { get; set; }

    public List<IFruit> Fruits { get; set; }

    public void AddBanana()
    {
        if (Bananas == null) Bananas = new List<Banana>();
        if (Fruits == null) Fruits = new List<IFruit>();
        var number = Bananas.Count;
        var newBanana = new Banana { Number = number, ContainedBy = this };

        // var lastBanana = Bananas[Bananas.Count - 1];
        // var index = Fruits.LastIndexOf(lastBanana);

        // Fruits.Insert(index + 1, newBanana);

        Fruits.Add(newBanana);
        Bananas.Add(newBanana);
    }

    public void DeleteBanana(Banana banana)
    {
        Bananas.Remove(banana);
        Fruits.Remove(banana);
        var n = 0;
        foreach (Banana b in Bananas)
        {
            b.Number = n++;
        }
    }
}

[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(600, typeof(Banana))]
public interface IFruit
{
    [ProtoMember(1, AsReference = true)]
    IContainer ContainedBy { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class Banana : IFruit
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Number { get; set; }

    public IContainer ContainedBy { get; set; }
}


static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var basket = new Basket();
        var root = new RootObject { Container = basket };
        basket.AddBanana();

        var clone = Serializer.DeepClone(root);
        Console.WriteLine(clone.Container.Fruits.Count == 1); // true
        Console.WriteLine(clone.Container.Bananas.Count == 1); // true
        Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(
            clone.Container.Bananas[0],
            clone.Container.Fruits[0])); // true
        Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(
            clone.Container.Fruits[0].ContainedBy,
            clone.Container)); // true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You. It works fine. Unfortunately I had to write update#1 due to another problem which appeared. Maybe its not that 'tricky' to need to switch to DTO.